# change wordpress naviagtion background on scroll of page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, header, navigation

I have a wordpress website making use of a thrive theme,

first of all I have customized my navigation header to be fixed and transparent.

But now i am trying to make my header/navigation bar change background colour from transparent on scroll of the page.

I checked online and presently I have tried to use jquery to change the colours, but no success, this is what I have tried

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#startchange');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $(".header").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
       } else {
          $('.header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
    }
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

and the class code css for my navigation and header

```
#floating_menu {position:fixed;}

header {
    background-color: rgba(52, 52, 52, 0);
}
```

can some one please tell me why this isn't correct, because obviously it isn't working for me.

this is the site for reference

```
http://beyonddigital.mu/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You code snippet comes before `jQuery` is included
2. `$` is not defined but `jQuery` is.

Check your browser console to see these errors.

Comment: do u have a better way of implementing this, cuz i honestly copied this from online

Answer (score 0):

On your site your header doesn't have a class but in you code you're targeting one.

```
$('.header')  //null
$('header') // <header class style>...</header>
```

Comment: iv edited my code to have $('header') //  but it still dosent work

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your time.

i was able to solve this by

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var a = $("#floating_menu").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > a)
    {   
       $('#floating_menu').css({"background":"red"});
    } else {
       $('#floating_menu').css({"background":"transparent"});
    }
});
});//]]>
```

should incase any one else needs it